# Django NoReverseMatch error but the url pattern works

Tags: django

Just finished adding a feature to my site that allows users to create sub blog posts(build logs). Everything was working fine but my url structure was poor so I am re doing it. Doing so has created an error

error:
[image]

Where I am confused is if I enter `/post/29/build-log/2` as the url the page works.

But when I go to the post page which lists the build logs it does not work

The '(2,)' it is refering to is the id of the first build log

views

```
def DetailPostView(request, pk):
model = Post
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
form = CommentForm

comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)#.order_by('-create')

buildlogs = BuildLog.objects.filter(post_id=post)

if request.method == 'POST':
    # A comment was posted
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)            
        new_comment.author = request.user
        new_comment.post = post
        new_comment.save()


context = {
    'post':post, 'form':form, 'comments':comments, 'buildlogs':buildlogs
    }
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

---

```
def BuildLogDisplay(request, pk, pkz):

model = BuildLog
post = BuildLog.objects.all().filter(post_id=pk)
log = BuildLog.objects.get(pk=pkz)

context = {
    'post':post, 
    'log':log
}

return render(request, 'blog/buildlog.html', context)
```

urls

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.DetailPostView, name='post-detail'),
path('post/<int:pk>/build-log/<int:pkz>', views.BuildLogDisplay, name='build-log-view'),
```

spent a few hours on it but cant figure it out

Comment: Did you check your template? For example: `{% url 'BuildLogDisplay' pk pkz %}`.

Comment: so i had it as `<a href="{% url 'build-log-view' buildlog.id %}">{{ buildlog.title }}</a>` so i changed it to `<a href="{% url 'build-log-view' buildlog.id buildlog.id %}">{{ buildlog.title }}</a>` and it worked. Not sure why tho

Comment: Because you declare your `def BuildLogDisplay(request, pk, pkz)`. So `url 'build-log-view'` need two arguments `pk` and `pkz`.

Comment: that makes sense. But when calling `buildlog.id` is that not calling the id field of the buildlog model?